# How to execute task in Gradle one by one

Tags: android, gradle

I have this gradle build file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
        classpath 'com.eriwen:gradle-css-plugin:1.2.1'
        classpath 'com.eriwen:gradle-js-plugin:1.5.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'js'
apply plugin: 'css'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/cordova-2.7.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
}

task MinifyJSForRelease {

tasks.add(name:"copyTask2", type:Copy){
    from 'assets/'
    into 'build/minifiedassets/assets'
}
it.dependsOn copyTask2
def tester = fileTree(dir:"build/minifiedassets/assets", include:"**/*.js");
println tester
tester.eachWithIndex {File file, idx ->
    tasks.add(name: "makeMinifyJS${idx}", type: com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask) {
        source = file
        dest = "${file.path}"
        closure {

            compilerOptions.languageIn = "ECMASCRIPT5"
        }

    }
}

it.dependsOn tasks.matching { Task task -> task.name.startsWith("makeMinifyJS")}
}

build.dependsOn MinifyJSForRelease

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17"

signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('keystores/mobilecoe_android.keystore')
        storePassword "mobilecoe"
        keyAlias "MobileCoE"
        keyPassword "mobilecoe"
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 16
}
buildTypes {
    debug {

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        }
    }

    release {

        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        zipAlign true
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['build/minifiedassets/assets']
            }

            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        }
    }
}
}
```

I Want to run the task `MinifyJSForRelease` like the first thing would be to copy the assets folder to where I want and then when that is finished I want to minify the JS files.
Now when I run the task it copies the folder but not reaching the end the next function says it has nothing to minify but if I run the task the second time(when the folder is already copied) it fiends it and does everything.

What am I do in wrong?
I need to:

1. copy folder
2. Get the folder and minify its js files

Could some one help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total virgen to Gradle, So I can only provide you with educated guess:

1. unify the way you declare the dependencies

   taskB.dependsOn tasksA
2. force the order of the task (in add of the dependency)

   taskB.mustRunAfter(taskA)
3. add logs, to see if the task is executed VS the tasks does not do what you expect.

Adding dependencies to a task / Ordering tasks

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html

please, provide us with the solution once you got it !